# Передача POST запроса с параметром JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, free-kassa

Не могу создать заказ в мерчанте который требует POST запрос. Можно ли реализовать это на JS? Необходимые параметры для передачи: shopId, nonce, signature, i, email, ip, amount, currency. Content type application/json. url для передачи: https://api.freekassa.ru/v1/orders/

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи POST-запроса на JS используйте [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Пример:

```
const data = { 
  shopId: 'example', 
  nonce: 'example', 
  signature: 'example', 
  i: 'example', 
  email: 'example', 
  ip: 'example', 
  amount: 'example', 
  currency: 'example' 
};

fetch('https://api.freekassa.ru/v1/orders/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Вместо **example** ставьте свои значения. Результат запроса обрабатывайте в методе **then**